# Failed to create or validate data directory for EmbeddedKafkaBroker

Tags: spring-boot, junit, apache-kafka, embedded-kafka

I am trying to run a simple unit test using @EmbeddedKafka Annotation.
As a reference, I am following the below spring documentation 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#embedded-kafka-annotation

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext
@EmbeddedKafka(brokerProperties = "log.dir=/kafka-logs", partitions = 1,
    topics = {
        "dare_policy_created"})
@Slf4j
public class ConsumerTest {

@Autowired
  private EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka;

@Test
  public void someTest() {
    Map<String, Object> consumerProps = KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps("testGroup", "true", this.embeddedKafka);
    consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    ConsumerFactory<Integer, String> cf = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerProps);
    Consumer<Integer, String> consumer = cf.createConsumer();
    this.embeddedKafka.consumeFromAnEmbeddedTopic(consumer, "dare_policy_created");
    ConsumerRecords<Integer, String> replies = KafkaTestUtils.getRecords(consumer);
    //assertThat(replies.count()).isGreaterThanOrEqualTo(1);
  }
}
```

I was trying to define the log.dir  @EmbeddedKafka(brokerProperties = "log.dir= ") because I was getting an error when running the Test.

I tried :

- log.dir=/kafka-logs
- log.dir=real_path_to_my_project/kafka-logs
- ...

But every time I run the test I get this error :

```
kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel.error - Failed to create or validate data directory /kafka-logs java.io.IOException: Failed to load /kafka-logs during broker startup

kafka.log.LogManager.fatal - Shutdown broker because none of the specified log dirs from /kafka-logs can be created or validated
```

Comment: I too am having this issue.  I got a little further by adding a meta.properties file to the log dir. Kafka tried to start but then failed with:
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.serverChannelBuilder(Lorg/apache/kafka/common/network/ListenerName;ZLorg/apache/kafka/common/security/auth/SecurityProtocol;Lorg/apache/kafka/common/config/AbstractConfig;Lorg/apache/kafka/common/security/authenticator/CredentialCache;Lorg/apache/kafka/common/security/token/delegation/internals/DelegationTokenCache;)Lorg/apache/kafka/common/network/ChannelBuilder;

Comment: I'm facing the same error too(+1), did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue by removing an explicit dependency on kafka-client.
I had below dependency in my pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```